# I need help understanding what a question is asking.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm not sure what this question is asking me to do. I know it sounds silly but could someone explain what i'm meant to do.

Give a satisfying assignment for the proposition (¬p ∨ ¬q) → r.

Comment: You need to decide for each letter $p,q,r$ whether it will be true or false, in such a way that $(\neg p \lor \neg q) \to r$ is true.

Comment: @MeesdeVries does that mean drawing a truth table?

Comment: That would work, then you could find a row in the truth table where the proposition is true, and use the assignments for $p,q,r$ in that row. However, you might be able to find the assignment without writing down an entire truth table.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Ok I understand now thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In general "satisfying a formula" means "making it true".

Answer (score 0):

Giving a satisfying assignment to a formula means finding a Model of the assignment.

So basically you have to find for which assumption your formula would be true.

You can check Satisfiability of a formula in two ways:

1. By writing a Truth Table.
2. By using the Semantic Tableau (or Truth Tree).

I personally prefer the second one, because it is faster and easier.